# How to paste to another app from a shell script

Tags: copy-paste, shell-command, automation

I've been getting very vexed by the following.

Goal: Take the clipboard contents and paste them into another application by using a shell script called by Emacs, followed by a Return. [This is for entering a command in another application.]

Problem: A shell script using automation tools (to simulate typing) which works from a Terminal window acts goofy when called by Emacs, because all paste actions happen only after the Emacs function has completed, so the Return precedes the pasting. [Negating the value of entering the command from Emacs.]

I put steps to illustrate the problem below.

The simplified example uses `xdotool`, but I had the same problem when using `xte`. The example pastes into gedit, but the problem exists for other applications as well. Finally, I tried both `shell-command` and `call-process-shell-command` and tried all possible settings of `select-enable-clipboard` and `select-enable-primary`, all to no avail. If only I could trip the paste before the Return, I would be happy.

FWIW, I've tried such things as shell-scripts calling shell-scripts and emacs functions calling emacs functions, but all I can get is having the paste happen at the very end. I'm clearly very lost.

Any ideas about how to get the paste to happen when it happens in the script?

Thanks,

Bill

Steps to duplicate problem, because the explanation above is likely not sufficient.

Here is `hunh.sh`---copy, paste, save it, make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool search --name --onlyvisible "gedit" windowactivate

# select text to replace
xdotool key ctrl+a
# paste in the clipboard
xdotool key ctrl+v
# do stupid stuff before finally hitting Return, so that it's clear
#    that the paste (ctrl-v) gets misplaced
xdotool key space space h u n h
sleep 1
xdotool key BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace
sleep 1
xdotool key Return
```

Here is in `hunh.el`. Copy it, paste it, save it as hunh.el, then load it in Emacs

```
(defun hunh ()
 (interactive)
 (funcall interprogram-cut-function "Fighting with clipboards is no fun")
 (shell-command "hunh.sh")
 )
```

1. Be sure that you have `xdotool`.
2. Assuming you have it, open a single window for gedit.
3. Type a bunch of garbage in the gedit window so that it can get replaced later.
4. Run the script `hunh.sh` from the place you're working: `./hunh.sh`

*Result:* Everything will work fine, with the text being replaced, some extra typing and deleting, and then a Return.

5. Start emacs
6. Within emacs, load hunh.el, then run its one function
   `M-x hunh`

*Result:* The text in gedit will be replaced with the extra typing and deleting, then a Return, and finally the paste of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect that the problem will disappear if you run the process in the background with `(shell-command "hunh.sh&")`

Comment: I had a similar problem and this solution works (thanks!): can you please explain why? I'd expect a `xdotool` script to work even with `call-process`, but it doesn't record mouse clicks.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that the X clipboard works by making applications register themselves as "I'm the one holding it" rather than by storing the content eagerly in the X server,  So when Gedit fetches the clipboard's content, it actually has to ask Emacs for it, but Emacs is stuck waiting for `call-process` to end before it can reply to those requests,

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know if this problem is present also in Wayland?