# How can I execute synchronously a xdotool process in an Elisp function?

Tags: process, async, subprocess, call-process, x-window

I want to perform a repetitive task using Emacs and another program (which, unfortunately, runs under X). I have then set up an elisp function and a `xdotool` script to do the two parts of the work. The elisp function uses a `cl-loop` to iterate over the lines of a temporary buffer I create.

I'd like the two to be synchronized, so that Emacs

- cannot continue until the `xdotool` script has finished
- it can also check the return code (potentially stopping if the script fails).

I'd normally do this with `call-process-shell-command`, but for some reason, then `xdotool` won't accept mouse clicks. I found in [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36897/how-to-paste-to-another-app-from-a-shell-script) that calling the process asynchronously solves the problem, and indeed it does:

```lisp
           (let ((async-shell-command-display-buffer nil))
             (shell-command "/home/alessandro/xorg-session.sh&"
                    nil
                    nil)
             )
           (sleep-for 5)
```

but then I can no longer wait for the process, and I'm forced to use an **extremely fragile** `sleep-for`. How can I do both? I.e., running a `xdotool`, but **synchronously** and checking for its success? I've heard about sentinels, but I don't think they can help here (due to the `cl-loop`).

Thanks!